# How to find posts associated with voting

Tags: support, feature-request, voting, meta

In terms of voting, the Meta FAQ mentions:

> [What does voting mean
>   here?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences)
>
> Voting here works a bit differently from the main site. On Meta,
>   voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to
>   point out a lack of quality or helpfulness. Please don't be concerned
>   if you receive downvotes – members of the community may simply
>   disagree with your bug, feature request, support issue, or the nature
>   of the discussion.

However, when I view my activity "fly-out"

[image]

there is no way (at least I could find) to identify the posts of mine that received the votes. For example, which posts do the +2 above refer to? How else would I know that I'm awesome or not so much?

Comment: I can assure you: You _are_ awesome.

Comment: In case there is still some doubt I agree with @doncherry :-). I was about to suggest that this would be available in your reputation history, but that does not seem to exist separately for meta???

Comment: @PeterGrill: True; it exists on Meta.SO, but that's a different beast altogether since you have "reputation" on that site.